# How to set Backbone Model.idAttribute?

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb, backbone.js, lithium

I'm using MongoDb/Lithium php framework with backbone.

I want all my model id(s) and idAttribute(s) to be same as my database document id (i.e '_id'/mongoid)

Questions:

1. When I print the value of model.idAttribute, it is shown as just _id.
2. When I print model.get('idAttriubte'), it is undefined.
3. How do I ensure that the idAttribute is set as the same as the database id/mongoid?

Here is the model class:

```
window.app.IHoliday = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: HOLIDAY_URL,
    idAttribute: '_id',
    id: '_id',
    // Default attributes for the holiday.
    defaults: {
    },

    initialize: function(props) {
    },      
});
```

Here is the view code, calling fetch on the model. The mongoid for the document is passed to this page as a hidden input (holiday_id).

```
console.log('Holiday URL:' + HOLIDAY_URL );
        var Holiday = new window.app.IHoliday({ _id: holiday_id });
        console.log('HOLIDAY before fetch: \n' + JSON.stringify(Holiday));
        Holiday.fetch(
                {
                    success: function(){
                        //alert('Holiday fetched:' + JSON.stringify(Holiday));
                        console.log('HOLIDAY Fetched: \n' + JSON.stringify(Holiday));
                        console.log('Holiday name:' + Holiday.get('holiday_name'));
                        console.log('Holiday id:' + Holiday.id);
                        console.log('Holiday idAttribute:' + Holiday.idAttribute);
                        console.log('Holiday idAttribute:' + Holiday.get('idAttribute'));
                    }
                });
```

The output from firebug console:

```
HOLIDAY before fetch:{"_id":"50bcaab24fbe3dfc1700000b"}
GET http://localhost:8080/li3/holidays/load/50bcaab24fbe3dfc1700000b 200 OK

HOLIDAY Fetched: 
{"_id":"50bcaab24fbe3dfc1700000b","holiday_name":"eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","description":"","star_rating":"3","holiday_type":"family","rooms":"1","adults":"2","child":"0","emails":""}

Holiday name:eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
Holiday id:50bcaab24fbe3dfc1700000b
Holiday idAttribute:_id
Holiday idAttribute:undefined
```

EDIT:
The following worked...after commenting out the entry for id in the model class:

```
    window.app.IHoliday = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: HOLIDAY_URL,
    //id: '_id',
    idAttribute: '_id',
    // Default attributes for the holiday.
    defaults: {
    },

    initialize: function(props) {
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`idAttribute` contains the name of the member of the class wich will be use as the id. So, if you use `idAttribute: '_id'`, Backbone will use the member `_id` as the id of your class.

If you want to use the attribute `holiday_id` as the id of your class `IHoliday`, you may try :

```
window.app.IHoliday = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: HOLIDAY_URL,
    idAttribute: 'holiday_id',
    // Default attributes for the holiday.
    defaults: {
    },

    initialize: function(props) {
    },      
});

var Holiday = new window.app.IHoliday({holiday_id : holiday_id });
```

Backbone will use the `holiday_id` attribute  instead of the regular `id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the line id: '_id' and just keeping idAttribute: '_id' did the trick!

Answer (score 5):

From Backbone [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute):

> If you're directly communicating with a backend (CouchDB, MongoDB) that uses a different unique key, you may set a Model's idAttribute to transparently map from that key to id.

So `idAttribute` just tells your Model class that any attribute with the same key as `idAttribute`'s value, should be also copied over to `id`. In the Backbone [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-44), this is done as follows:

```
if (this.idAttribute in attrs) this.id = attrs[this.idAttribute];
```

Basically if you're trying to set an attribute with the same name as `idaAttribute`, that value is also copied to `id`.

So to answer your question: `idAttribute` doesn't store the `id`, but it stores the name of the attribute that holds the `id`

Comment: Thanks @Jakee for explaining this in detail. However I now tried by commenting out the line idAttribute: '_id' in my model class and now the URL generated by fetch() call is messed up as it now does not pick the correct model id, even though the model.id is mapped to _id when the model is created: URL now created is following (which is incorrect):
GET http://localhost:8080/li3/holidays/load/_id